# Comparing 2 strings, one from file and one declared

Tags: perl

This program doesn't print that the strings are equal but when they get printed, they appear to be the same...someone please explain

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$str =  "print \"I want this to work\\n\";";
print $str."\n";
open FILE, "<", "check2.doc" or die "buhuhuhu";
my $str2;
while (<FILE>) {
$str2 = $_;
}
close FILE;
print "$str2\n";
if ( $str eq $str2) {
print "they are equal\n";
```

But when the output comes there is this extra line at the bottom due to the second string $str2

```
print "I want this to work\n";
print "I want this to work\n";
-----empty line-----
```

Here is the file check2.doc

```
print "I want this to work\n";
```

Does anyone know why they are not equal???

Comment: ...Is there a blank line in the file? Try comparing the lengths of the two strings. If the newline char is part of the file, str2 should be one character longer than str1.

Comment: @ban [**if one of the below answers solve your problem kindly mark one as the right answer, see here how.**](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 0):

The file read includes the `\n`, so you have to remove it:

```
$str2 = $_;
chomp $str2;
```

And, if your file has only one line, replace the while loop by:

```
$str2 = <FILE>;
chomp $str2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The line in the file is created by

```
$str."\n"
```

Of course that's not equal to

```
$str
```

You need to remove the trailing newline.

```
my $str2 = <FILE>;
chomp($str2);
```